# Access string resources through static properties

Tags: wpf, localization, windows-8

In Windows Phone classes are generated for my .resx-files. I can access them through static properties like this: `AppName.Resources.AppResources.MyButton_Caption`.

Is there any equivalent in Windows Store apps using .resw-files?

`ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetValue("MyButton_Caption").ToString()`

is in my opinion less maintainable and I do not see why not both options should exist.